# Calendar software to schedule replacement personal

Tags: calendar, scheduling

Here is the workflow that I want to make:

1. **Teacher A**:

   - Reports sick ("schedules an appointments") he/she specifies the following parameters:

     1. His/Her name
     2. **School X**
     3. Date and time
     4. Some info (Example: explanation)
2. **Coordinator**:

   1. Checks new "appointments"
   2. Assigns a **Replacement Teacher B** (**Coordinator** has the knowledge, no extra automation needed.
   3. Adds extra info (Example: contact information)
3. **Principal X** can view the schedule by their school they see:

   - All "appointments" for **School X**

     1. Teacher A Name
     2. Replacement Teacher B Name
     3. Date and Time (Calendar will show it)
     4. Infos (Some info + extra info)

Would prefer online and it is fine if it is a paid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that https://www.bitrix24.com/ can be tailored for this.

What you need is not exactly an online appointment application.
What you need is an online small business tasks managing application.
Where one (teacher) submits one task (in this case absence), manager (coordinator) assigns it to another person (replacement teacher) and other people from the department (school principal) can view it too.

Comment: You could improve your answer by listing some features of it.